# VueJs Conditional Rendering v-if not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, zurb-foundation, nuxt.js

Can you help me figure out what happen when I try to use v-if and props?

I created a modal component and inside that modal component, I have multiple modals and I use Zurb Foundation Reveal to show my modal. I use `v-if` directive to specific display the modal I want.

Here is my code:

**Modal Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="type === 'loading'" id="modal-1"></div>
    <div v-if="type === 'success'" id="modal-1"></div>
    <div v-if="type === 'error'" id="modal-1"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"

export default class MyModal extends Vue {
  @Prop(string) type
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-modal :type="type"></my-modal>
    <button @click="myMethod()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"
import MyModal from "../my-modal.vue"

@Component({
  components: { MyModal }
})
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  type: string = ""
  myMethod() {
    let modal = new Foundation.Reveal($("#modal-1"))

    this.type = "loading"
    modal.open()

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're trying to initialise the modal before "type" is set, so there's no element on the page to initialise at all, thus no modal to actually open. Set the type, then initialise the modal.

Comment: change `type` in the parent component to be a computed property, so it will be reactive and changes on the parent `type` will affect the child prop.

Comment: @ChrisDixon uhmmm type will set after i click coz i want to show modal i want so it should be set upon click. or is there other way to do it ?

Comment: @AgentDroid just try to put this.type = "loading" before the "let modal.." line. Does that work? The first job is to get the modal initialising.

Comment: @ChrisDixon i tried but it return this error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

Comment: @Efrat how to set using computed ?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the modal type and wait for the next tick so the DOM is updated and can be manipulated by this plugin.

```
myMethod() {
    this.type = "loading"

    this.$nextTick().then(_ => {
        let modal = new Foundation.Reveal($("#modal-1"))
        modal.open()
    })
  }
```